# Cumulative sum through years R

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to obtain a cumulative sum through years and for each entity.

Here below an example, and what I have tried so far:

```r
data<-data.frame(id=c("a","a","a","b","a","b","b"),cars=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1),year=c(2001,2001,2002,2003,2003,2003,2004))
```

## I have tried :

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data %>% group_by(id,year) %>% mutate(csum = (cumsum(cars))) %>% top_n(1, csum)
  id     cars  year  csum
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 a         1  2001     2
2 a         1  2002     1
3 a         1  2003     1
4 b         1  2003     2
5 b         1  2004     1
```

This is what I would like:

```r
  id     cars  year  csum
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 a         1  2001     2
2 a         1  2002     3
3 a         1  2003     4
4 b         1  2003     2
5 b         1  2004     3
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Your code is using literals `a` and `b` instead of strings.

Comment: First summarize: `data %>% group_by(id,year) %>% summarize(cars=sum(cars))  %>% arrange(id,year) %>% group_by(id)  %>%  mutate(csum = (cumsum(cars))) %>% top_n(1, csum)`

Comment: You have a record for "a" in 2003. Where is that values supposed to go in your desired output? What determines the "id" for the year?

Comment: Sorry for the mistakes, I did the corrections

Comment: Is `cars` always 1? Are years always consecutive with no gaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you need is `aggregate`, you can use it this way :

```
aggregate(x=data$cars, #column on which you want to apply a function
          by=list(id=data$id,year=data$year),#grouping variables
          FUN=sum)#function to apply
```

Answer (score 2):

```
dat %>% group_by(id) %>% count(cars,year) %>%
mutate(csum = cumsum(n)) %>% select(-c(cars,n))
# A tibble: 5 × 3
# Groups:   id [2]
  id     year  csum
  <chr> <dbl> <int>
1 a      2001     2
2 a      2002     3
3 a      2003     4
4 b      2003     2
5 b      2004     3
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this work?

```
data %>% group_by(id, year) %>% summarise(sum_cars = sum(cars)) %>% 
group_by(id) %>% mutate(csum_cars  = cumsum(sum_cars), .keep = 'unused')
```

Output:

```
# Groups:   id [2]
  id     year csum_cars
  <fct> <dbl>     <dbl>
1 a      2001         2
2 a      2002         3
3 a      2003         4
4 b      2003         2
5 b      2004         3
```